# Работа с текстом, не может вывести в консоль больше 1 строки из текстового документа Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Выдает ошибку:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at Boss.KingZ.main(KingZ.java:20)

Что находится в текстовом документе из которого программа должна читать (синим выделено)
[image: Текстовый документ]

Сам код :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String lineFromFile;
        String s = File.separator;
        String path = s+ "Users" +s+ "Иннокентий" +s+ "eclipse-workspace" +s+ "BossCheck" +s+ "src" +s+ "Boss" +s+ "Logs.txt";
    
        try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader
                (new FileInputStream(path), "Windows-1251")){
            try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)){
                while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
                    
                    lineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    String[] str2 = lineFromFile.split("[CHAT]" + "был повержен за ");
                    
                    str2 = str2[1].split(" ");
                    int time = Integer.parseInt(str2[0]);
                    int min = 60;
                    System.out.println( + time + 10*min);
                    
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();{
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Прошу помочь, для меня этот проект как новичку очень интересен.

Comment: вы пытаетесь поделите строку по `lineFromFile.split("[CHAT]" + "был повержен за ")`, но подстроки "[CHAT]был повержен за" у вас нет, поэтому данный метод вам возвращает массив в котором 1 элемент - исходная строка

Comment: И как это решить?

Comment: Сначала проверьте существование str2 = str2[1].split(" ");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените кодировку и разделитель строки:

```
   try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader
            (new FileInputStream(path), "Windows-1251")) { // кодировка UTF-8
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
            while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
                lineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
                String[] str2 = lineFromFile.split("был повержен за "); // разделяем строку
                if (str2.length > 1) { // проверяем, что строка была разделена по паттерну выше
                    str2 = str2[1].split(" ");
                    int time = Integer.parseInt(str2[0]);
                    int min = 60;
                    System.out.println(+time + 10 * min);
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так попробуйте

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String lineFromFile;
        String s = File.separator;
        String path = s+ "Users" +s+ "Иннокентий" +s+ "eclipse-workspace" +s+ "BossCheck" +s+ "src" +s+ "Boss" +s+ "Logs.txt";
    
        try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader
                (new FileInputStream(path), "Windows-1251")){
            try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)){
                while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
                    
                    lineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    if (lineFromFile)
                    String[] str2 = lineFromFile.split("[CHAT]");
                    if (str2.length > 1 && str2[1].split("был повержен за ").length > 1) {
                       str2 = str2[1].split("был повержен за ")[1].split(" ");
                    }
                    int time = Integer.parseInt(str2[0]);
                    int min = 60;
                    System.out.println( + time + 10*min);
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();{
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Неразрешимая проблема компиляции: 
 Несоответствие типов: невозможно преобразовать String[] в String

 at Boss.KingZ.main(KingZ.java:18)

Comment: Извините исправил

Comment: выдает ошибку - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ывывфыввыфывф"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
 at Boss.KingZ.main(KingZ.java:20)

Comment: А так думаю получится. Конечно топорно но проблему решит

Comment: Что-то пошло не так
https://imgur.com/a/U3W5mRd